# Native Flutter App OGP - How do I implement Open Graph Protocol?

Tags: flutter, hyperlink, facebook-opengraph

I've seen many tutorials for implementing OGP with Flutter web apps or with React Native mobile apps, but I can't seem to find any tutorials or information other than a few packages like https://pub.dev/packages/ogp_data_extract.

I essentially want to be able to send users friend requests with an image attached. I store a given users profile image in Firestore, say I can access that with no problem. How can I send that image, and maybe modify it a little to add a bit of text, as a link for this friend request? Right now my friend request links work but they're plain text.

The text looks something like this: ://.com/acceptFriendRequest?userRef=

Any advice or directions I can look would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I've tried just sending a string like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Let's be friends!">
<meta property="og:description" content="Join me on the app!">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/my-image.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="<site>://<site>.com/acceptFriendRequest?userRef=<someHash>">
```

But it sends to the user as plain text like that